# Calling sprintf function

Tags: c, printf, scanf, c-strings

I am using MySQL queries in R to insert data in the databases plus am using also string variables to insert data into the databases.

I am getting this error :

> format not a string literal and no format arguments [`-Wformat-security`]

Here's the code

```
void add_data_to_the_table(MYSQL * connection){
    char schlName[200]={};
    printf("Enter the school name  \n");
    scanf("%s",schlName);
    char query_string[] = { "INSERT INTO schools(schoolName) VALUES(%s)" };
    sprintf(schlName, query_string);
    if (mysql_query(connection,buf)) 
    {
     validate(connection);
    }
}
```

I was expecting to insert the string into the table `schools` in the database but instead I got the error above.

Comment: Picture what happens when your `query_string` has a percent sign in it. Where's the corresponding argument to `sprintf()`?

Comment: And why are you populating `schlName` with a `scanf()` call (You really need to check its return value to make sure it worked, btw) and then immediately overwriting it with `sprintf()`?

Comment: BTW, never create query strings like that.  Consider what happens when I say my school name is `'Roberts'); DROP TABLE schools --`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters this initialization of an array

```
char schlName[200]={};
```

is incorrect in C. The list of initializers in the braces may not be empty. Write instead

```
char schlName[200]={ '\0' };
```

In the call of sprintf the order of the arguments is invalid. It seems you mean

```
sprintf( result_string, query_string, schlName );
```

instead of

```
sprintf( schlName, query_string);
```

where result_string is a string where the output will be redirected.

The declaration of the function `sprintf` looks the following way

```
int sprintf(char * restrict s, const char * restrict format, ...);
```

So if the argument that corresponds to the parameter format has a conversion specifier like `%s` then you need to supply at least three arguments.

Pay attention to that this call

```
scanf("%s",schlName);
```

is unsafe. Use `fgets` instead of `scanf`.